Chrome developer tools: Why is the network request filterbar not shown?
In my chrome developer tools, why can I no longer see the filterbar used to filter network requests by type? I haven’t disabled it, and if so it was unintentional (I'm not even sure it can be disabled).
(Chrome Version 124.0.6367.119)


Click the filter button in red again to enable the filter, it will bring back the filters by type.

@Sidonai Fantastic, thanks. Do you wanna write an answer so I can upvote you?

Click the funnel/filter button in red again to show the filter, it will bring back the filters by type.
